# RestKit error when testing iOS application on device

Tags: xcode, restkit

I am receiving a lot of "sematic issue" errors when trying to test my iPhone application after installing my provisioning profile from Apple.

It has worked perfectly during the development period, however since I set up my provisioning profile, each time I try to build I receive the errors below (80 when my physical device is selected and 10 when using simulator):

```
RKRequest.h: error: Semantic Issue: Redefinition of 'RKRequestMethod' 
RKRequest.h: error: Semantic Issue: Redefinition of enumerator 'RKRequestMethodPOST' 
...
```

I retrieved the version of RestKit from its git repository about a month ago and it has been working perfectly until now.

Here is a sample from the error detail:

```
In file included from /Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-
bpcvkhxzjupqmibdvvipchdfecpi/Build/Products/Debug-
iphoneos/include/RestKit/CoreData/../ObjectMapping/../Network/RKClient.h:21:
```

I have tried clearing this directory but the problem persists and have included a screenshot below:

[image]

Here's an example of how RestKit is used in the app:

## MyViewController.h

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import <RestKit/CoreData/CoreData.h> 

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<RKObjectLoaderDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, SelectTranslationDelegate>
...
```

## MyViewController.m

```
@interface MyViewController()
{
}
@end
...

@implementation MyViewController
...
```

## My Linked Libraries

[image]

Does anybody have any suggestions as to why this might be?

Comment: will you check if you haven't accidentally #imported a .m file instead of .h ?

Comment: Hi mja. Thanks for the tip. I have checked and only see .h files in imports.

Comment: I added in a sample of usage in case that helps. RestKit is referenced in the header files of all required view controllers and in the app delegate.

Comment: Do you have any paths pointing to RestKit dir in your Build Settings (eg. header search)? Also, what are your Target Dependencies in "Build Phases" tab? What libraries you link against? (RestKit.framework or libRestKit.a)?

Comment: Header Search Paths points to "$(SOURCE_ROOT)/RestKit/Build", there are no target dependencies in Build Phases for my main app and I've added my linked libraries to the main question in the form of a screenshot.

Comment: Do you have multiple targets in your project? (Not counting the ones added by RestKit). Maybe you can try updating RestKit to master, they simplified the build process a lot recently (Now, there is just one lib to link against&fewer RestKit targets)

Comment: Thanks mja. I'll try doing this. Do you know of any docs detailing exactly what I need to link to in the new version. There's a possibility I used some old docs to add my linked libs etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6381/discussion-between-nick-and-mja)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the screenshots and our chat conversation i can tell you are using an outdated version of RestKit. Recently, they significantly simplified the build process and submitted a number of iOS5 fixes so the update is worth it.

1. run `git pull` in the RestKit directory
2. remove `#import <RestKit/CoreData/CoreData.h>` from your files. Just #`import "RestKit/RestKit.h"` should do the trick
3. Remove all RestKit libs from "Link Binary With Libraries", be sure to add new `libRestKit.a` and `libxml2.dylib`
4. Try building the project, if you see any errors try removing derived data in Organizer.

Comment: This fixed my problem and my app now successfully builds and runs on my device. Thanks again.

Comment: The official wiki has been updated with installation instructions for the latest version. https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

Comment: Ran into this same issue today with xCode4.  Everything was setup correctly.  For some reason I needed to remove derived data.  That fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, check your project 'Build Phases' in Xcode and make sure you have't got more than one entry for each of the RESTKit .m files (or a stray .h), in the 'Compile Sources' list.

Comment: Hi Herwr. Thanks for the comment. I have checked my project and included are local project files only. The RestKit files are not included here. I have also included a screenshot in the original question.

Comment: For clarity, I added in a sample of usage in case that helps. RestKit is referenced in the header files of all required view controllers and in the app delegate.